# Is there a way to conditionally set 'unique' in Mongoose Schema?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongoose

I came across a problem while implementing user deletion functionality. A

Suppose I have a model:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
        {
            email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
            name: { type: String, required: true },
            password: { type: String, required: true },
            deleted: {type: Date, default: null}
        },
        { timestamps: true }
    );
```

This clearly states that the field `email` has to be unique. However, I would like to set it unique only in the set filtered for `deleted != null`.

In other words, I would like to filter out the deleted users' records before checking if it is unique or not.

Are there any best practices regarding this?

Or should I just create a field called `del-email` and null the email field to avoid over-complication and preserve the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

**[Partial index with unique constraint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-index-with-unique-constraint):**

- The partial unique index, you can specify the filter expression condition, if it matches then the unique index will take the role,

```
UserSchema.index(
   { email: 1 },
   { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { deleted: { $eq: null } } }
);
```

> **Note:**
> As noted in the [query coverage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#query-coverage) documentation for partial indexes: 
> To use the partial index, a query must contain the filter expression (or a modified filter expression that specifies a subset of the filter expression) as part of its query condition.
>
> ```
> User.find({ email: "something@mail.com", deleted: null });
> ```